# function with no parameter and the main function?

Tags: idris, idris2

Book "Type-driven Development with Idris" page 52 has

> 2.5 Summary ...
>
> - Function types have **one or more** input types and one output type.
> - The entry point to an Idris program is the main **function**, which must have type IO (), and be defined in the module Main.

The main **function** is defined as

```
main : IO ()
```

From my limited knowledge, without `->` it is a variable rather than a function given that the summary states that a function must have at least one input.

I must miss something but why does the author call main, whose type has no arrows, a function?

In addition, can I call `foo : Bar` a function?

Comment: the first bullet point talks about function types, not functions. That then moves the question to "why isn't the type of the `main` function a function type"? I don't know, but I can well imagine he called it a function cos it's a function in C, Python, Java etc and he was used to calling it that. `main` is after all, being the program entrypoint, a bit special even in Idris, even if just in how it's used